# Замена элемента в матрице.Нормальный вывод на экран

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, вывод, матрицы

Дана матрица,каждый элемент вычисляется по формуле: **math.sin(n*(i+1)+m*(j+1)))**.
если значение элемента отрицательное то нужно заменить его на 0. Как это сделать?(где у меня прокол)
 И как в данном случае вывести эту матрицу столбцом, а не кучей списков? Существует ли универсальный метод?

```
import math

a = [[0]*4 for i in range(4)]
m=4
n=4
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j]=(math.sin(n*(i+1)+m*(j+1)))
        if(a[i][j]<0):
            a[i][j]==0 

print(a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там, где вы проверяете условие на отрицательное значение, надо использовать знак присваивания `=`, а не равенства `==`. `a[i][j]==0` данное выражение просто возвращает истину или ложь, которое никуда не присваивается, поэтому у вас отрицательные значения не заменялись, но и исключений не возникало.

Что вы подразумеваете под универсальным методом вывода?

```
import math

a = [[0]*4 for i in range(4)]
m=4
n=4
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j]=(math.sin(n*(i+1)+m*(j+1)))
        if(a[i][j]<0):
            a[i][j] = 0 # Тут надо присвоить значение  

print(*a, sep='\n') # Вывод по строкам в виде списков
print()

# Вывод просто в виде матрицы
for i in a:
    print((len(i) * '{:.2f} ').format(*i)) # ':.2f' - число знаков после запятой менять тут
```

Comment: В выводе в виде матрицы лучше форматирование вместо `str` использовать типа `def str(val): return '{:5.4f}'.format(val)`

Comment: Что такое `print(*a, sep='\n')` . ( Sep= )?

Comment: Универсальный метод вывода ,ето, кагбе шаблон кода который можна применить везде, и не расписывать все индивидуально.

Comment: @AwesomeMan, `sep` - параметр, в котором задается строка-разделитель между элеметами выводимой последовательности. По поводу применения шаблона "везде" - если вы подразумеваете вывод матриц, то оберните кусок кода в функцию.